# Exercise: Limit of two sequences; am I doing this correctly?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

My first sequence looks like

$b_n=\frac{1+(-1)^n}{n}$

so I check subsequences with odd and even indexes:

$b_{2k}=\frac{1+(-1)^{2k}}{2k}=\frac{2}{2k}$so its going to 0

and

$b_{2k-1}=\frac{1+(-1)^{2k-1}}{2k-1}$ and it's going to 0 as well

so limit point is 0

and for sequence

$c_n=(2+(-1)^n)\frac{n}{n+2}$

$c_{2k}=(3)\frac{2k}{2k+2}$ and limit of this going to 3

$c_{2k-1}=(0)\frac{2k-1}{2k+1}$ and limit of this going to 0

so limit points are 0 and 3.

Is it correct, or I missed something?

Comment: Check your work on $c_{2k-1}$ again. The others look good.

Comment: thanks, my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is fine except for your computation of $c_{2k-1}$. It should be $(1)\frac{2k-1}{2k+1}$, which tends to $1$. Thus, the limit points of $(c_{n})$ are $1$ and $3$.

Comment: oo thanks i see, stupid mistake